# Is a quiver representation a variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, quiver, algebraic-stacks

I 've heard that a quiver representation $R_{Q}$ of a quiver $Q$ is a variety (I guess they mean an algebraic variety). Is this is the case we know that an algebraic variety is given by the zero set of a collection of polynomials. **In the case of quivers what is this zero set that makes them form an algebraic variety?**

Furthermore in every node (vector space) we assign the natural action of the endomorphisms. If we quotient out the representation by this action we obtain a stack.
$$ R_Q / \prod_i G_{\text{dim}V_i}(Vi) $$
Here $V_i$ denotes the vector space that lives in the $i$-th node of $Q$. Is this the usual algebraic stack we talk about in algebraic geometry? Can I think of it as an orbifold with some singular points? And what these points would be?